# How can I set an attributes (base on child attributes) in jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set an attribute on hover, based on his child attributes, by using jQuery. I have tried many ways to make this, but no luck. All attributes are same and not changing on hover.

```
<li class="menu-item">
  <a data-src="" class="menu-item-link" href="#">Item one</a>
  <span class="description">
    <img  src="https://i.ibb.co/LxSKFgH/image1.jpg">
  </span>
</li>

<li class="menu-item">
  <a data-src="" class="menu-item-link" href="#">Item two</a>
  <span class="description">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TLJL7hq/image2.jpg">
  </span>
</li>
```

What I want is when I hover on `.menu-item` I want to set `.description`'s img attribute on `data-src` attribute for each menu. That means Attribute must set on his parent attribute.

Comment: So: when you hover `.menu-item`, you want to change the `src` of the `img` to whatever the `a`s `data-src` is?

Comment: you should include your jquery/javascript code

Comment: Yes @YaakovAinspan . I want this

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Hi @DaFois I have tried with this 
https://pastebin.com/q3tXHwsE

Comment: Hi @YaakovAinspan, I have tried with this pastebin.com/q3tXHwsE

Comment: Please put the code in the question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by executing the following jQuery script:

```
$(".menu-item").hover(function(){
   //Take the src value from the inner img tag
   let srcValue = ($(this).find("img").attr("src"));
   //Set the data-src attribute of the inner anchor tag
   $(this).find("a").attr("data-src", srcValue);
});
```

Comment: Work like a charm! Thanks